# How should I track down PHP Warning: Input variables exceeded 1000

Tags: php

I have a relatively high traffic site, that about once per day generates the error message:

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0

My guess is that it is caused by some crawler that has found a URL link structure that never ends.  However, I couldn't find any thing in the access logs that would be a problem (e.g. a url with a 1000+ get parameters).

It there an easy way to get insight into this Warning?  It happens before any php scripts are loaded, so I assume it is impossible to introspect with php.  If I had simple details such as the URL, it would be easy to solve.

Comment: Maybe someone is sending POST data with many variables to one of your scripts/files. Find out the time of the PHP warning and then look through your access logs for that time. Then maybe you will find your file and the IP address of the person/crawler or whatever.

Comment: this could be an attempted (dumb) attack.

Comment: Isn't there a referer line after that warning? Something like: `referer: http://example.com/dir/file.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it only happens occassionally and potentially also affects end users it's actually rather safe to [just raise the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16470573/1729885) - it's a limitation imposed for practical reasons to circumvent possible attacks.

Practically, to debug this I'd dive into edge cases. In a real world scenario I'd indeed expect this error to only occur when something is nested indefinitely. I'd insert a small detection script somewhere in code that's always included, for example:

```
function detectLargeInputs($name, $array)
{
  if(count($array) > 500)
    mail('mymail@domain.tld', 'Large input in '.$name, 
         print_r($array, true).print_r($_SERVER, true));
}
detectLargeInputs('GET', $_GET);
detectLargeInputs('POST', $_POST);
detectLargeInputs('COOKIE', $_COOKIE);
```

This should show the problem within a day, including the `$_SERVER` info that also has fields like `REQUEST_URI` and `HTTP_REFERER` which should help you pinpoint the issue exactly.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  This would certainly work.  For some reason, it didn't occur to me that it is just a warning not an error, so the php code is actually running.  I was able to track down the error by using timestamps, though it was not easy since there are about 50 RPS.  The issue was POST data, and it was a javascript error logging thing.  Someone's browser has a plugin that generates 1000s of javascript errors, and it was overloading the js error logging script.

Comment: Actually I was assuming it was an error too - that's why I set the mail threshold at 500 instead of 1000  :)   Good to know it's fixed though.

Answer (score 0):

Attention! This detection won't alert if the input vars are in an sub array:
Array
(
    [foo] => 100
    [bars] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1111
            [1] => 1111
...(more than 1000)
        )
)

The return value of 'count' will be 2 and everything seems ok but PHP won't handle the more than 1000 values in the sub array.