# JQuery Submit Large Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, submit

I'm trying to submit a form using AJAX, but keep getting

`Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini`

Up to now I've been using serializeArray() and then sending that to my php page. In my PHP page I've been using the following to read the submitted data:

`$var = $_REQUEST['var_name'];`

This works fine when there are only a few values submitted, but fails as above on a large page.  Some of my form fields are named as `$value[]` so I can have multiple entries returned for them.

I'm now trying to get the following to work:

```
var tmp = $('#form').serialize();

$.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: {myData : tmp},
        url: "helper.php?action=submit&region=" + REGION,   
})
```

When this submits I get my individual values for **action** and **region** and then one very long string of `myData`

How do I process `myData` so I can use each individual value and submission from it ? ideally in a similar why to my previous method of $var = $_REQUEST for each entry.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `$('#form').serializeArray()`?

Comment: I think this question duplicate. please see this one [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470527/warning-input-variables-exceeded-1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470527/warning-input-variables-exceeded-1000/%22Warning:%20Input%20variables%20exceeded%201000%22)

Comment: try this $params = array();
parse_str($_POST[myData], $params);

Comment: `serializeArray()` always results in the same error `Input variables exceeded 1000`.

Comment: @JYoThI  `parse_str(): Input variables exceeded 1000.`

Comment: @Tom Did you solve your problem now?

Comment: I have now solved it using `JSON.stringify` & `serializeArray` and then processing the results in PHP back to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

First on your php file check all the data is coming or not by below code:

```
 print_r($_POST) or var_dump($_POST)
```

greetings :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I get the data as one long string. How do I process that ?

Comment: like this
$_POST["fieldname"];

Comment: Thanks, but the data returned in `myData` is one long string.  Made up like this `["myData"]=> string(39328) "method[]=0:4551512:2&address[]=LOCAL&home[]=NW&access[]=&user[0]=0"`  I've shortened this.. How Do I get all the `method[]` values from it ?

Comment: I think:
 echo ['myData']['method'];

please try this.

Comment: I get : `Illegal string offset 'method' in` any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

use `parse_str()`

```
$params = array();
parse_str($_POST['myData'], $params);
```

Comment: `parse_str(): Input variables exceeded 1000`

Comment: temporary  try this set ini_set('max_input_vars','2000'); @Tom

Comment: Thanks I will try that, but I'd like to find a method that works regardless of the amount of data submitted.

Comment: max_input_vars should always be set to 10k or more