# CSV Export reaches 500 lines then stops

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I have an export function that converts data posted from a form into a CSV file. The issue is when the number of rows exceeds 500 it stops the CSV.

My php.ini file shows that my `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` equates to 0. So it should be unlimited, so my assumption is that it's not form size that's the issue.

My current code looks like this:

```
$data = $_POST['ids'];

$ebayMmlSql = 'SELECT `UKM_Make`, `UKM_Model`, `UKM_CCM`, `UKM_Submodel`, `Year`, `UKM_StreetName`
               FROM `ebay_mml`
               WHERE `ePID` = :epid';

$aiSql = 'INSERT INTO `model_epid_matches` (`epid`, `model_id`) VALUES (:epid, :model);';

$rows = array();

$i = 0;

foreach ($data as $key => $ids)
{
    foreach ($ids as $id)
    {
        if (isset($id['epid']) && $id['epid'] !== '') {
            # run select
            $ebayMmlQry = $handler->prepare($ebayMmlSql);
            $ebayMmlQry->execute(array(':epid' => $id['epid']));

            # if insert is true, run insert
            if (isset($_POST['insert']) && $_POST['insert'] == true) {
                if (isset($id['new']) && $id['new'] == true) {
                    $aiQry = $handler->prepare($aiSql);
                    $aiQry->execute(array(':epid' => $id['epid'], ':model' => $id['mod_id']));
                }
            }

            $rows[$key][$i]['action'] = ($i == 0 ? 'Revise' : '');
            $rows[$key][$i]['item_id'] = ($i == 0 ? 'Insert ItemID for '. $key : '');
            $rows[$key][$i]['relationship'] = ($i == 0 ? '' : 'Compatibility');
            $rows[$key][$i]['relationship_details'] = '';

            foreach ($ebayMmlQry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $k => $value)
            {
                $rows[$key][$i]['relationship_details'] = 'UKM_Make='. $value['UKM_Make'] .'|';
                $rows[$key][$i]['relationship_details'] .= 'UKM_Model='. $value['UKM_Model'] .'|';
                $rows[$key][$i]['relationship_details'] .= 'UKM_CCM='. $value['UKM_CCM'] .'|';
                $rows[$key][$i]['relationship_details'] .= 'UKM_Submodel='. $value['UKM_Submodel'] .'|';
                $rows[$key][$i]['relationship_details'] .= 'Year='. $value['Year'] .'|';
                $rows[$key][$i]['relationship_details'] .= 'UKM_StreetName='. $value['UKM_StreetName'];
            }

            $i++;
        }
    }

    $i = 0;
}


# testing count of rows before gen_csv_file on screen
# $total = 0;

# foreach ($rows as $key => $row)
# {
#    echo '<pre>';
#    var_dump($key. ': ' .count($row));
#    echo '</pre>';

#    $total += count($row);
# }

# var_dump($total);

gen_csv_file($rows, 'ebay.csv');

function gen_csv_file($data, $file)
{
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. $file);
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');

    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    fputcsv(
        $output,
        array(
            'Action(SiteID=UK|Country=GB|Currency=GBP|Version=941)',
            'ItemID',
            'Relationship',
            'RelationshipDetails'
        )
    );

    foreach ($data as $key => $row)
    {
        foreach ($row as $item)
        {
            fputcsv($output, $item);
        }
    }

    fclose($output);
}
```

I can't seem to get to the root of the issue - maybe memory issue?

## update

@AymDev linked this question: [Warning: Input variables exceeded 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470527/warning-input-variables-exceeded-1000)

Was a good read, however:

1. The highest voted answer led me to var_dump the count of $_POST which returned 1 (though that doesn't exceed 1000 so not sure why it doesn't work?)
2. The accepted answer suggests setting `Content-Type` in the header which I've already done

I could always set the `max_input_vars` via `ini_set`/.htaccess to avoid changing on server ...

Comment: do you have a log error ? With your information i supposed your script reach the max time limit. Try to upgrade your max_timelimit or use set_time_limit(0) function in your loop to unlimited time

Comment: @Inazo it wasn't timeout limit - but I didn't even consider it being a PHP error - but looking in there does show `Input variables exceeded 1000` - will set this and see if it works

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470527/warning-input-variables-exceeded-1000) could help ?

Comment: @AymDev it does to some extent - though `var_dump`ing the count `$_POST` shows a count of 1 so doesn't exceed 1000 :S And the accepted answer uses a `Content-Type` fix which already exists in my code

Comment: @AymDev will update question with found info as is useful to see

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs yes I knew the accepted answer wouldn't help ^^ I generate .csv everyday but not this size, never encountered this error :/

Comment: @AymDev no worries, can't imagine it happens daily to people haha :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs so do you have an error message in your log ?

Comment: @Inazo not an error, but a warning - saying about the max_input_vars being exceeded

Comment: try to unset your $data in your  gen_csv_file() function to remove variable as used like this :
`foreach ($data as $key => $row)
    {
        foreach ($row as $item)
        {
            fputcsv($output, $item);
        }
 unset($data$key]); 
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to create a .htaccess file. After @Inazo's comment I checked my logs and saw this:

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini

I first increased my limit in the .ini file to 25000 and tested the code. Everything worked, but it did feel wrong to set it to an excessive amount. After @AymDev linked another question I saw someone suggest `ini_set` or using the .htaccess file.

Using `ini_set('max_input_vars', 25000)` at the top of my script changed nada, but using .htaccess like this:

```
php_value max_input_vars 25000
```

It worked - so it wasn't at script level, but server level. Though still doesn't explain why count of `$_POST` returned 1 and yet still exceeded 1000.

Comment: yes some values can't be edited by the ini_set function