# Form tag with request of more 1000+ request not able get in controller in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-formrequest

When I am requesting all parameters than it is giving me NULL

My Controller **store function** as:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     dd($request->all());
}
```

My view file as:

```
@extends('main')
@section('content')

<form class="add_form" id="add_form">
@csrf
<input type="text" name="param_1" >
.
.
.
.
till 1450 parameters
<button type="button" id="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>

@endsection
@push('scripts')

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").on("click",function(e){
      
        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"{{ route('froms.store') }}",
          data: new FormData($('#add_form')[0]),
          processData: false,
          contentType:false,

          success: function(data){
            if(data.status==='success'){
                  location.reload();
            }else if(data.status==='error'){
                  location.reload();
            }
          }
        });
      
    });
  });
</script>

@endsection
```

Output that I am getting on store function is `NULL`

Now problem with this is that if I am using parameters less than 1000 than I am getting all request in my controller but when I am using it with more than that not able get request

Apart It is compulsory to have all request at a time not able to do parietal forms also.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this issue is related to PHP configuration (php.ini) file Check the `post_max_size` and `max_input_vars` increase these values if necessary.

You can find php.ini file on linux on given path.

```
/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
```

[image]

[image]

Or you can try `JSON.stringify()` function while sending ajax request. By using this you can reduce the size of the data being sent in the AJAX request

For More information read [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470527/warning-input-variables-exceeded-1000).

Tried this scenario on my local environment
[image]

Comment: I have changed both variable, but still it is showing same error not able to get all requested parameters.

Comment: Did you restarted your apache server after changing variable values?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted my server and also checked whether those variables are being set or not, it is also updated with new values, In approx 24 hours I have tested it with restart an approx 4 times, but still its not solving my problem, (Even my param are on approx 2500 I have set php variable with 10000.)

Comment: Ok. Then I don't think this issue is from your code. Because I tried this scenario on my local environment, screenshot attached in my answer, worked perfectly. This is server related issue only. Check if on your server any **Firewall system** is installed or any configuration related to **Apache Hardening** has been done.

Comment: Thanks, By changing my default setting and after making changes as per above you said, perfectly works for me.